# Polymorphism in Java and relationship between classes and methods

Tags: java, polymorphism

So I'm learning about polymorphism in java and trying to understand how this code works and what it does step for step. Here is the code

```
Hamburger h = new Hamburger ();
FastFood food1 = h;
Food food2 = new Hamburger();
Item item1 = food2;
Item item2 = new Stone();

Eatable e1 = new Hamburger();
Eatable e2 = new FriedRice();
```

From what I understand Hamburger is a class, h is an object. But what is Food and FasFood? Eatable is interface if I'm correct, is it even a method in Hamburger class? And what would happen if object food2 is used instead of object h?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this sentence: Eatable is interface if I'm correct, is it even a method in Hamburger class?

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that your code is really Java and that it compiles without an error, you are right, `Hamburger` is a class; you can say that because you can instantiate it by calling `new` with the respective constructor (in Java, constructor will have the name of the class they belong to). Same for `Stone` and `FriedRice`.

`h`, `food1`, `food2`, `item1`, `item2`, `e1` and `e2` are *not* objects, they are references to objects of different types (see below). The difference is subtle, but required if you want to understand some other concepts of Java; first, that `null` is not an object …

Whether `FastFood`, `Food`, `Item` and `Eatable` are classes or interfaces cannot be said. You can assign objects to the respective references that are from a different class type. This means, that an instance of `Hamburger` must be also an instance of `FastFood`, `Food`, `Item` and `Eatable`, otherwise the respective assignments would fail. But you can achieve that from both, having a class hierarchy (`Item` <- `Eatable` <- `Food` <- `FastFood` <- `Hamburger`) or by all four being interfaces that are implemented by `Hamburger` (or by a mixture of this, some being parent classes, others being interfaces …).

Java does not allow to distinguish classes and interfaces by names, there is not even a commonly accepted convention for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't distinguish a class from an interface simply by name.

I'd say it's highly possible that `Eatable` is an interface and `Food` and `FastFood` are classes, but it's impossible to know that by just the snippet you posted.

At most we can say that `Hamburger`, `Stone` and `FriedRice` are concrete classes because you're instantiating them successfully.